# How to create thread local memory without syncronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, c++14

I want to give each thread that enters a function an object only it will use (in this case, it represents a page of memory).  This is to help cut down on synchronization my program is bottle-necking on, so it itself should ideally not need to lock a mutex.

minimalist example of what I'm trying to do (`std::map` cannot be inserted into concurrently, but if it could, this would do precisely what I need):

```
// multiple threads can access this, they should be able to do so without synchronization
void addJob(ThreadMemory * mem){

    // straight-forward, but undefined when used concurrently:

    static std::map<std::thread::id, ThreadMemoryPool> memPool;
    memPool[std::this_thread::get_id()].addRef(mem);

    // if memPool has no node for this thread, one is inserted,
    // every thready would be guaranteed one ThreadMemoryPool object

}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same... um general effect that those two lines would like to accomplish without needing a lock?

Comment: thread_local std::map<std::thread::id, ThreadMemoryPool> memPool - try this declaration

Comment: @chornoxor - .... that's a Thing??  That would remove the need for the map altogether!

Comment: Compiler-supported thread-local variables are much more efficient than any other implementation, since they just use a segment register (usually `%fs` or `%gs`). But note that thread-local variables 1. are slightly sensitive to whether they are from the executable or a shared library, and whether they are used from the main thread or a different thread, and 2. are not async-signal-safe, since they require malloc-on-first-use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will use the same memPool for all threads and its modification is not thread-safe.

If you want to have thread local instance of memPool you have to declare it with 
thread_local specifier:

```
thread_local std::map<std::thread::id, ThreadMemoryPool> memPool;
```

In this case each thread will use its own instance of memPool.